# Как найти количество различных цифр в натуральном числе?

Tags: python

Например в числе 5677 их 3, а в 121212 их 2

Comment: а как ты без питона выяснил, что их 3 и 2? вот точно так же сделай и с питоном

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется написать коротко, то можно как-то так:

```
print(len(set(str(x)))
```

Comment: Ребус однако ))  Нам то понятно...

Comment: не, ну тут чистый минус. Надо же 5677 и 121212, а не какое-то ч 

Comment: @Эникейщик, тьфу, опять раскладку не сменил)

Comment: @CrazyElf, поправил)

Comment: @Qwertiy не, до исправления лучше было :)